# twine showing "No such file or directory" error

Tags: python, pythonpath

I'm running a Ubuntu 18.04 system, recently installed a new ssd and mapped $HOME onto the ssd then moved the existing files onto it.  Somehow, in that process I've mucked up my PYTHONPATH, I believe.

If I run `twine upload dist/*` I get the following error:

> bash: /home/henry/.local/bin/twine: No such file or directory

If I run `pip install twine`, I get the following output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: twine in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7.0 in /home/henry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from twine) (39.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pkginfo>=1.4.2 in /home/henry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from twine) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: readme-renderer>=21.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from twine) (24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0 in /home/henry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from twine) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.14 in /home/henry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from twine) (4.23.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-toolbelt>=0.8.0 in /home/henry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from twine) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Pygments in /home/henry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from readme-renderer>=21.0->twine) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/henry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from readme-renderer>=21.0->twine) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach>=2.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from readme-renderer>=21.0->twine) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.13.1 in /home/henry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from readme-renderer>=21.0->twine) (0.14)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /home/henry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0->twine) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /home/henry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0->twine) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/henry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0->twine) (2018.1.18)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /home/henry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0->twine) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bleach>=2.1.0->readme-renderer>=21.0->twine) (0.5)
```

`echo "PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH"` gives me `PYTHONPATH=`

What do I do to correct?

Comment: twine is  in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` (1.12.1)

Comment: yes.  And what do I do?

Comment: try using , `pip uninstall  twine` then install it again `pip install twine`

Comment: I've done that - it didn't work

Comment: try this `python -m twine  upload dist/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
python -m twine upload dist/*
```